# Obfuscate PHP for Apache

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have got lots of php code served by Apache (WAMP). Can I use a tool like

- Bambalam
- PHC-WIN
- Phalanger

to wrap the php code so that Apache can still serve those files?

*Its for commercial use*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Those tools compile PHP-Code to (some kind of) native code. They do not obfuscate code (for this, there are a lot of tools easily found by googling "php obfuscator") but turn them into a language that apache with php doesn't understand.

you could try to use these native programs via  CGI, but it will be a PITA to set up & maintain.

also, keep in mind that obfuscating offers just a relatively small bit of code protection. if your customer really, really wants to reconstruct the code, he can.